# Accessing column from Collection of Collection using Hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate, collections

Req.hbm.xml:

```
    <id name="reqId" type="long" column="REQ_ID"> 
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">SEQUENCE</param> 
        </generator>
    </id>


    <bag name="lines" lazy="false" >
        <key column="REQ_ID" not-null="true" />
        <one-to-many class="com.Lines" />
    </bag>
```

Lines.hbm.xml

```
    <id name="lineId" type="string" column="LINE">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <property name="reqId" type="long" column="REQ_ID" />

    <bag name="comments">
        <key column="LINE" />
        <one-to-many class="com.Comments"/>
    </bag>
```

Comments.hbm.xml:

Req.java will contain list of lines. and Line.java have list of comments.

While retrieving columns using projections... how can i retrive columns from CMNTS table.

lines.comments.commentId can i use in Projection and can i retrieve the column?

How do define joins in criteria class for CMNTS table?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't just go "lines.comments.commentId", you need to use a projection alias to traverse multiple collections. Have a look at Projections.alias()